# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_name'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='encoder_output')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='decoder_input')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

decoder = Model(inputs=autoencoder.get_layer('decoder_input').input,outputs=autoencoder.output)
```

I after running this code, I get this error.
What I want to do, is to extract the decoder from the autoencoder.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271644/extract-encoder-and-decoder-from-trained-autoencoder), where they extract it with the index of the layer. But I don't know the index.

```
decoder_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
decoder = Model(decoder_input, autoencoder.layers[-1](decoder_input))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where these examples come from but dissecting the API to create these models are not the intended usage. If you look at the [blog post](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) from the author of the library, it is best to separate encoder and decoder as such:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)

decoder_input = Input(shape=(32,))
decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(decoder_input)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)
decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded)

autoenc = decoder(encoder(input_img))
autoencoder = Model(input_img, autoenc)
```

The key thing is `Model` is just another layer, in fact it inherits from `Layer` class. So you can create smaller models and then use them just like layers.