# Input 0 is incompatible with layer global_average_pooling2d_4: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2 error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am trying to fine-tune a VGG16 model. I have removed the last 5 layers

```
(*block5_pool (MaxPooling2D),flatten(Flatten),fc1 (Dense),fc2 (Dense),predictions (Dense)*).
```

Now, I want to add a global average pooling layer, but I am getting this error

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer global_average_pooling2d_4: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2**

what seems to be the problem here?

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
x = model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
```

Comment: global average pooling layer yes it must be also 4d as other layers and you have some 2d input to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to remove the last four layers, then just use `include_top=False`. Further, use `pooling='avg'` to add a `GlobalAveragePooling2D` layer as the last layer:

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg')
```

---

A note about why your original solution does not work: as already suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52282558/2099607), you can't use `pop()` method on `layers` attribute of the models to remove a layer. Instead, you need to reference their output directly (e.g. `model.layers[-4].output`) and then feed them to other layers if you want to add new connections.